# Import error with scikit-dsp-comm package downloaded from GitHub in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, signal-processing

I'm trying to use the scikit-dsp-comm package for a signal processing course. I followed the procedure from https://scikit-dsp-comm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html and it seems to download fine. But when I try to follow the first example on [this](https://scikit-dsp-comm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nb_examples/Continuous-Time%20Signals%20and%20Systems%20using%20sigsys.html) page, i get a squiggly yellow underline and the error message

```
Import "sk_dsp_comm.sigsys" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)".
```

This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sk_dsp_comm.sigsys as ss
```

If I try to run it says

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sk_dsp_comm'
```

From what I can see the package has been downloaded into C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs and I tried adding that to the path but no luck.

I don't know if I've made a mistake in the way I've downloaded it as I'm pretty new to using GitHub and pip install etc., or if I added the wrong thing to the path, or if there's something else.

I've done my best to check that all versions are compatible, which they appear to be.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is VS Code using the same `python` that was used to install the downloaded package?

Comment: I think so, is there any way for me to check this?

Comment: In VS Code, you can see (and select) which python and/or python environment it is using.